# Python for-loop repeatedly outputting the input() for every iteration of dictionary contact_emails(not what I want)

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, iteration

```
   contact_emails = {

         'Sue Reyn' : 's.reyn@email.com',
         'Mike Filt': 'mike.filt@bmail.com',
         'Nate Arty': 'narty042@nmail.com'
             }

         new_contact = input()

         new_email = input()
         contact_emails[new_contact] = new_email

         for contact in contact_emails:
                      print(new_contact + ' is ' + new_email)
```

The output I want is

```
s.reyn@email.com is Sue Reyn
mike.filt@bmail.com is Mike Filt
narty042@nmail.com is Nate Arty
alf1@hmail.com is Alf
```

the output I get it

```
Alf is alf1@hmail.com
Alf is alf1@hmail.com
Alf is alf1@hmail.com
Alf is alf1@hmail.com
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I fix this code to make it output what I would like it to output?

Comment: What would you like it to output?

Comment: You explicitly tell it to print out the new email and contact. If you wanted to print out the contact you're iterating over you should use that variable.

Comment: I had to edit the question because when I tried to put what I wanted outputted, stackoverflow wouldn't let me post because it thought the output was code.

Comment: Try `print(contact + ' is ' + contact_emails[contact])`

Comment: rdas your answer is very close. My output was:                                               Sue Reyn is s.reyn@email.com
Mike Filt is mike.filt@bmail.com
Nate Arty is narty042@nmail.com
Alf is alf1@hmail.com                                                                                           But i'm trying to get                                                                                      s.reyn@email.com is Sue Reyn
mike.filt@bmail.com is Mike Filt
narty042@nmail.com is Nate Arty
alf1@hmail.com is Alf

Comment: So try `print(contact_emails[contact] + ' is ' + contact)`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for contact in contact_emails:
>     print(new_contact + ' is ' + new_email)
> ```

You are printing the new contact again and again. What you need to do is something like this:

```
for contact, email in contact_emails.items():
    print(email + ' is ' + contact)
```

This iterates all the key, value pairs of your dictionary.

Comment: In my opinion using `items()` is the best solution because there is no need to do a lookup for the value again.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using this

```
contact_emails[new_contact] = new_email
```

try this

```
contact_emails.update({new_contact:new_email})

for key,val in contact_emails.items():
    print(key +' is ' + val)
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re iterating over each `contact` in `contact_emails`, but the variable `contact` doesn’t appear in the `print` call. You can access the email using the name held in `contact`:

```
...
for contact in contact_email:
    print(contact_email[contact], 'is', contact)
```

Remember that `new_email` and `new_contact` are assigned *outside* of the loop so do not change on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Learn more about iterating the dictionaries here - [How to Iterate Through a Dictionary in Python](https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/)

```py
contact_emails = {
    'Sue Reyn' : 's.reyn@email.com',
    'Mike Filt': 'mike.filt@bmail.com',
    'Nate Arty': 'narty042@nmail.com'
    }

new_contact = input()

new_email = input()
contact_emails[new_contact] = new_email

for contact in contact_emails:
            print(contact_emails[contact]+ ' is ' + contact)
```

Output:

```
>>Alf
>>alf1@hmail.com
s.reyn@email.com is Sue Reyn
mike.filt@bmail.com is Mike Filt
narty042@nmail.com is Nate Arty
alf1@hmail.com is Alf
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for my little brain.

```
for contact, email in contact_emails.items():
    print('{} is {}'.format(email, contact))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample output with inputs: 'Alf' 'alf1@hmail.com' is this one:

```
mike.filt@bmail.com is Mike Filt
s.reyn@email.com is Sue Reyn
narty042@nmail.com is Nate Arty
alf1@hmail.com is Alf
```

The Dictionary `contact_emails` is already of size 3, and contains detail of three contacts. When a new input of contact and email address is appended, the question asks to display all of the four contact with their email ids. Here is how it can be done:

```
contact_emails = {
    'Sue Reyn' : 's.reyn@email.com',
    'Mike Filt': 'mike.filt@bmail.com',
    'Nate Arty': 'narty042@nmail.com'
}

new_contact = input()
new_email = input()
contact_emails[new_contact] = new_email

for key,val in contact_emails.items():
    print(f'{val} is {key}')
```

The Output now is :

```
s.reyn@email.com is Sue Reyn
mike.filt@bmail.com is Mike Filt
narty042@nmail.com is Nate Arty
knguyen@qmail.com is Kate Nguyen
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
contact_emails = {
    'Sue Reyn' : 's.reyn@email.com',
    'Mike Filt': 'mike.filt@bmail.com',
    'Nate Arty': 'narty042@nmail.com'
}

new_contact = input()
new_email = input()
contact_emails[new_contact] = new_email

for new_contact in contact_emails:
    print(contact_emails[new_contact] + ' is ' + new_contact)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for new_contact in contact_emails:
    print(f'{contact_emails[new_contact]} is {new_contact}')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will pass the question for you, no need for any functions.

```py
for contact in contact_emails:
     print(f"{contact_emails[contact]} is {contact}"
```